# Função Editar no CRUD em PHP (PDO) não edita

Tags: php

```html
<?php
include_once "conexao.php";

try {
 
 $id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 $codigoproduto = filter_var($_POST['codigoproduto']);
 $codigobarras = filter_var($_POST['codigobarras']);
 $nomeproduto = filter_var($_POST['nomeproduto']);
 $valorcusto = filter_var($_POST['valorcusto']);
 $valorvenda = filter_var($_POST['valorvenda']);
 $quantidadeatual = filter_var($_POST['quantidadeatual']);
 $minestoque = filter_var($_POST['minestoque']);
 $maxestoque = filter_var($_POST['maxestoque']);
 $validade = filter_var($_POST['validade']);
 $unidmedida = filter_var($_POST['unidmedida']);
 $ncm = filter_var($_POST['ncm']);
 $cest = filter_var($_POST['cest']);
 $pesoliquido = filter_var($_POST['pesoliquido']);
 $pesobruto = filter_var($_POST['pesobruto']);
 $fornecedor = filter_var($_POST['fornecedor']);
 
 $update = $conectar->prepare("UPDATE produtos SET codigoproduto = :codigoproduto, codigobarras = :codigobarras, nomeproduto = :nomeproduto, valorcusto = :valorcusto, valorvenda = :valorvenda, quantidadeatual = :quantidadeatual, minestoque = :minestoque, maxestoque = :maxestoque, validade = :validade, unidmedida = :unidmedida, ncm = :ncm, cest = :cest, pesoliquido = :pesoliquido, pesobruto = :pesobruto, fornecedor = :fornecedor WHERE id = :id");
 $update->bindParam(':id', $id);
 $update->bindParam(':codigoproduto', $codigoproduto);
 $update->bindParam(':codigobarras', $codigobarras);
 $update->bindParam(':valorcusto', $valorcusto);
 $update->bindParam(':valorvenda', $valorvenda);
 $update->bindParam(':quantidadeatual', $quantidadeatual);
 $update->bindParam(':minestoque', $minestoque);
 $update->bindParam(':maxestoque', $maxestoque);
 $update->bindParam(':validade', $validade);
 $update->bindParam(':unidmedida', $unidmedida);
 $update->bindParam(':ncm', $ncm);
 $update->bindParam(':cest', $cest);
 $update->bindParam(':pesoliquido', $pesoliquido);
 $update->bindParam(':pesobruto', $pesobruto);
 $update->bindParam(':fornecedor', $fornecedor);
 $update->execute();
 
 header("location: index.php");

} catch(PDOException $e){
 
 echo 'Erro: ' . $e->getMessage();
 
}

?>
```

```html
<?php 

include_once "conexao.php";

 $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 $consulta = $conectar->query("SELECT * FROM produtos where id = '$id'");
 $linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
 ?>
 
<form action="editar.php" method="POST">
    Código do Produto: <input type="text" id="codigoproduto" name="codigoproduto" value="<?php echo $linha['codigoproduto'] ?>"><br>
    Código de Barras: <input type="number" id="codigobarras" name="codigobarras" value="<?php echo $linha['codigobarras'] ?>"><br>
    Nome do Produto: <input type="text" id="nomeproduto" name="nomeproduto" value="<?php echo $linha['nomeproduto'] ?>"><br>
    Validade: <input type="date" id="validade" name="validade" value="<?php echo $linha['validade'] ?>"><br>
    Valor de Custo: <input type="number" id="valorcusto" name="valorcusto" value="<?php echo $linha['valorcusto'] ?>"><br>
    Valor de Venda: <input type="number" id="valorvenda" name="valorvenda" value="<?php echo $linha['valorvenda'] ?>"><br>
    Quantidade Atual: <input type="number" id="quantidadeatual" name="quantidadeatual" value="<?php echo $linha['quantidadeatual'] ?>"><br>
    Mín. em Estoque: <input type="number" id="minestoque" name="minestoque" value="<?php echo $linha['minestoque'] ?>"><br>
    Máx. em Estoque: <input type="number" id="maxestoque" name="maxestoque" value="<?php echo $linha['maxestoque'] ?>"><br>
    Unidade de Medida: <select id="unidmedida" name="unidmedida" value="<?php echo $linha['unidmedida'] ?>"><br>
     <option>Quantidade</option>
     <option>Kilograma</option>
    </select>
    NCM: <input type="number" id="ncm" name="ncm" value="<?php echo $linha['ncm'] ?>"><br>
    CEST: <input type="number" id="cest" name="cest" value="<?php echo $linha['cest'] ?>"><br>
    Peso Líquido: <input type="number" id="pesoliquido" name="pesoliquido" value="<?php echo $linha['pesoliquido'] ?>"><br>
    Peso Bruto: <input type="number" id="pesobruto" name="pesobruto" value="<?php echo $linha['pesobruto'] ?>"><br>
    Fornecedor: <input type="text" id="fornecedor" name="fornecedor" value="<?php echo $linha['fornecedor'] ?>"><br>

 <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $linha['id'] ?>"/><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Editar"/><br>
</form>
```

```html
<?php

try {

 // Faz conexão com o banco de dados
 $conectar = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=db;", "root", "");

} catch (PDOException $e) {

 // Caso ocorra algum erro na conexão com o banco de dados, exibe a mensagem
 echo 'Falha ao conectar com o banco de dados: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: Muito código, pouco texto. Por favor, leia o guia de [ask].

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o que pretende, complete o seu código com um texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$update->bindParam(':nomeproduto', $nomeproduto);
```

acho que falta isso

Comment: Era isso mesmo!! OBRIGADO